# MySQL - VB - Erro de conexão

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, conexão, reportviewer

Boas tenho um erro, ao tentar fazer a ligação ao MySQL num relatório acompanhado por um *ReportViewer* está-me a dar um seguinte erro..

Já tentei criar um utilizador com todos os acessos no *Workbench* no erro anterior mas agora deparo-me com este.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A password não esta mal, nem o id.

Alguém me consegue solucionar ou explicar o porquê?

Comment: Relacionado: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-native-pluggable-authentication.html

Comment: Preço desculpa a ignorância, mas não percebi.